# get API methods - Class or Module

Tags: ruby, class, oop, module

This is a code design question.

I have a set of methods that make API calls to fetch the data which application would consume to perform it's task. These methods require same 2-3 variable inputs to fetch the data they need to. I want to wrap up these methods into a Class or Module but I am not sure what to use. Using a class feels weird to me as I am just using these methods to read data using API.

Any suggestions? Added the sample methods below for reference. Should I just use modules for methods like these or wrap them in a class. If I use class I may not have to pass similar parameters for each method.

```
module Client
    module Features
        def get_feature_set(client, version, locale)
          //code
        end
        def get_feature_detail(feature_id, client, version, locale)
          //code
        end
        def get_locales(client)
          //code
        end
  end
end
```

Comment: Your description is too vague to advise on. Can you add some example of the methods you have so far and how you call them?

Comment: Added the sample code. @AlexWayne, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like every method needs a `client`. Therefore I would think about initializing a class with this `client`. Perhaps with a interface like this:

Instead of `Client::Feature.get_locales(client)`:

```
Client.new(client).locales
```

Instead of `Client::Feature.get_feature_set(client, version, locale)`:

```
Client.new(client).feature_set(locale, version)
```

Instead of `Client::Feature.get_feature_detail(feature_id, client, version, locale)`:

```
Client.new(client).feature_detail(feature_id, locale, version)
# or
Client.new(client).feature_set(locale, version).details(feature_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a module for common code with common methods.
And call "include" from your class to include the common methods in your specific classes. (mixins)